# Problems with JRuby debug IDE

Tags: ruby

I am trying to get the debugger to work for JRuby 1.7.3:

I installed the ruby-debug / base / ide gems. I then tried to run a basic Ruby script on Aptana and NetBeans. In both cases I get the following trace:

```
Fast Debugger (ruby-debug-ide 0.4.17.beta16, ruby-debug-base 0.10.5.rc3) listens on 127.0.0.1:55687
Hello World
10432: Exception in DebugThread loop: Bad file descriptor - Bad file descriptor
Backtrace:
org/jruby/RubyIO.java:2052:in `close'
  from: C:/jruby-1.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.4.17.beta16/lib/ruby-debug-ide/interface.rb:44:in `close'
  from: C:/jruby-1.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.4.17.beta16/lib/ruby-debug-ide/ide_processor.rb:102:in `process_commands'
  from: C:/jruby-1.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.4.17.beta16/bin/../lib/ruby-debug-ide.rb:121:in `start_control'
  from: org/jruby/RubyProc.java:261:in `call'
  from: org/jruby/RubyProc.java:213:in `call'
```

I am now using the prerelease versions but I get the same error when using the release build.

A note: I successfully debugged using the built-in Ruby interpreter in NetBeans (not JRuby).

Comment: Are you still having this issue? If not then please close/delete the question.